# Integration of LinkedIn, Facebook and Google+ in Phonegap

Tags: cordova

Is their anyone , who has implemented the Facebook, LinkedIn and Google+ in phoneGap.
If anyone has done, Can anyone share the code or links of it.

Comment: can u please be more specific

Comment: I am new to the phonegap, now we have requirement to integrate the social network like facebook, twitter and linked, i have done with twitter can you help me in linked and facebook

Answer (score 1):

Is you using Phonegap on **iOS** you can use the following plugins:

- [Facebook Connect Plugin](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/) ([Video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVxFGiIoPgk))
- [Twitter plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/Twitter) (for iOS 5 and higher)
- For Linkedin but also Twitter and Facebook you can use [the ShareKit plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ShareKitPlugin)
- Google+ ???

If you using Phonegap on **Android** you can use the following plugins:

- [Facebook Connect Plugin](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/) ([Video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlpBgWiel2w))
- [Twitter plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Twitter)
- Linkedin ???
- Google+ ???

Answer (score 0):

Google+ https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

Example screenshot when logging in on Android:
[image]