# Linkedin login for a Cordova app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have a Cordova app - for Android and iOS platforms, and a feature in the app where user needs to login with their linkedin credentials.
The linkedin login is used to retrieve the user's profile information.
I have questions as below - 
1. In the "Add New Application" screen, what is the URL I have to mention at "OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs:" field?
2. Is there a defined procedure on how to integrate in the app?

I have searched on SO and found these links - [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133012/integration-of-linkedin-facebook-and-google-in-phonegap), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904330/how-to-connect-likedin-with-phonegap), [Link 3](http://www.benwagner.net/mobile/linkedin-developer-api-javascript-domains-cordova-mobile-app/)
These are of not a straight help as I tried giving "file:///...." in the Redirect URL as given in Link3 above.

Please, could anyone help/guide me how to implement this?

I have an Inapp browser plugin only at the moment, how to get the linkedin login work with this setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SocialGap plugin and it works. Cordova inappbrowser is a prerequisite. Thanks to SocialGap.
The documentation for integration [can be found here](https://github.com/YanchWare/SocialGap)

Comment: Is it possible to fetch the user profile info with SocialGap?

Comment: SocialGap allows you to perform the Linkedin authentication. The next steps after login should be done on your own. :)
Use this console to test your API calls...
For user profile information, you may use this as your URL in your HTTP request/AJAX call
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,industry,email-address,location:(name),three-current-positions)?oauth2_access_token=" + accessToken;

Comment: That link really helped ! I was using  api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~ and getting some cross domain error.

Comment: Can I have a +1 for that? :D

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day :)

Comment: On the repo we can notice: `Latest commit on 30 Jan 2015`